# Will a .NET Webservice break when I add a Property to a Parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have a .NET Webservice which hosts a Method called AddMyObject.

```
[WebMethod]
public void AddMyObject(MyObject[] objects){...}
```

Where MyObject is declared as

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Pro1{get;set;}
    public string Pro2{get;set;}
}
```

If I now add a Property to MyObject, the Client creates a new Proxy from the new WSDL and uses this Property, will an old instance of the Webservice be able to handle it? Of course the new Property will be `null`, but will there be any Exception?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately I just found the time to write a little test service for this issue.

What actually happens is, that if a property is added on client side, it's ignored on the old service.

Even when a Property is deleted on the client side, there is no Exception on the server: the Property is just `null`.

Comment: Note that you can control this more in WCF, where you can mark things as required.

Comment: And all of this is different if your client is for instance Apache axis

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general it will fail. Not neccessarily on a .NET client  (it's fairly lenient) but other clients will fail.

Answer (score 0):

That is a good question, +1 for that.

I  have never tried it, but I would say that it will probably work. Please tell us the results  :)